# How to move arrow left on dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap 3.3.7.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>Single select example
    <div class="selectRow">
        <select id="singleSelectExample">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here how it looks on the client:

[image]

Here is working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/678/)!!!

My question is how to move arrow left.

Here how I want it to be:

[image]

How can I achieve the desired appearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the question has anything to do with bootstrap, but here is the answer:

```
.select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}

.select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-chosen {
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/679/)

Comment: yes you are right but the default `margin-right` was `26px` so make sure to make the `margin-left: 26px` also add `.select2-container .select2-choice {padding: 0 8px 0 0 !important}`

Comment: If you add `margin-left: 26px` it will push text too far from the arrow. I will ignore the second suggestion as you have used `!important` :)

Comment: No need for `!important` since he put the overridden css as the last reference to be load, but I put it just in case :)

Comment: Thanks for post.Any idea how can I make select to look like boorstrap element(i mean like bootstrap select element)?

Comment: Have you seen https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/? It will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change Below Css

```
.select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-chosen {
    margin-left: 16px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.select2-container .select2-choice .select2-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;

    background-clip: padding-box;

    background: #ccc;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #ccc), color-stop(0.6, #eee));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center bottom, #ccc 0%, #eee 60%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #ccc 0%, #eee 60%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#eeeeee', endColorstr = '#cccccc', GradientType = 0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ccc 0%, #eee 60%);

}
```

Comment: can you check my css also?

Answer (score 0):

add below css in your page

```
.select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-chosen{
         float: right;
         position: relative;
         margin: 0px;
       padding-left: 5px;
}

.select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-arrow{
         float: right;
         position: relative;
         margin: 0px;
       border-radius: 0;
}
.select2-container .select2-choice{
      padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Native <select> solution

Currently, you just need to set `appearance: none` to the `select` tag, the detail is that the arrow will disappear, so you need to replace it with another one and locate it where you like, using a background image like in this example will work well in all major browsers.

```css
select {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
background-position: 98% 50%;
background-size: 12px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8, \
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 60 40'> \
  <polygon points='0,0 60,0 30,40' style='fill:black;'/> \
</svg>");
padding-right: 1.5em
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```